Pandas Python - formula column issues
Having issues creating a new column in a pandas python dataframe that does the same as the excel output attached. This takes two processes and compares which runs better than the other on the same environment . This is represented by the %improvement column this compares the difference between the last record  that was on the same environment. I am unsure how to replicate this on python pandas or if it is possible.
def BuildTable(self,Datatable):
                    Datatable['%improve'] = Datatable.apply(" apply formula here ")
                return Datatable



not sure I understand your question, please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

For any pandas.apply operation you're going to do, it depends on whether you want to use multiple columns of a single row and then apply a formula, or a single column. I'm not sure which one do you want, so I'll paste both:
Given the dataframe:



col1
col2
col3




2
3
4



Case 1) You want to use multiple columns ON THE SAME ROW:
If you want to create a new column "new_col" that uses col1 and col2 for example, you can do the following:
def apply_function(row):
   col1 = row["col1"]
   col2 = row["col2"]
   if col1 > col2:
      row["new_col"] = True
   else:
      row["new_col"] = False
   return row

df = df.apply(apply_function, axis=1)

You can use mathematical formulas or whatever you want in its place.
Case 2) You want to use apply a function based on a SINGLE COLUMN:
df["new_col"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: apply_function(x))

Beware that apply operations are very slow.
